# Excel - Sort cells by a number of matches

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data in cells A1 to E1.
all of them numbers.
e.g. 6, 13, 13, 3, 15, .

I would like to sort them in a way, that the largest number of matches come first, then the highest number and be followed by the lower numbers, lowest being the last.

So, ideally the result should be this:

13,13,15,6,3.

I counted the number of matches the following way:

H1 = COUNTIF($A1:$E1,A1) and spread it from H1 to L1.

Then, Sorted the appearance frequencies:

N1 =LARGE($H1:$L1,1), 
M1 =LARGE($H1:$L1,2), and so on and got proper sorting by number of matches:

2,2,1,1,1

Now I would like somehow to link the sequence and frequense of matches to the original data. Could someone advise of such a formula, please?

Comment: it probably can be done with formulas, however, this reached the complexity where I think VBA would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `A2`, **array formula****:

`=INDEX($A1:$E1,MATCH(LARGE(COUNTIF($A1:$E1,$A1:$E1)+$A1:$E1/10^6,COLUMNS($A:A)),COUNTIF($A1:$E1,$A1:$E1)+$A1:$E1/10^6,0))`

Copy as far as `E2`.

It has been assumed that each cell in the range `A1:E1` will always contain a numeric.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This is PERFECT! A brilliant solution. Do you mind walking us through the formula, especially the division by 10^6 part? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is practical in your situation, but if you can convert the columns to rows, you can do it quite simply.

[image]

[image]

Simply using `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` in B1 and dragging down, then sorting by `Column B`, then by `Column A`. However, if you need it in columns, you may need a VBA solution.