# Excel - Sort the data by number of matches, then by highest to lowest order

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have previously asked the same question, but the answer I had is based on array formula and slows down Excel when working with the large data and works for only numerical values.

Example: Cells A1 to E1 contain maximum of 5 numbers. e.g. 22,3,34,22,7. 
Objective: in cells F1 to J1 (No VBA, No Array formulae) Sort the cell entries by highest number of match first, in case of equal number of matches, highest number first, lowest number last. So, in this example the sorted data should look like: 22,22,34,7,3.

I am trying to use IF, COUNTIF and LARGE functions' combination. (I realize the formula will be quite long, but I don't mind).

Example formula for F1 entry:

=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,1))>1,COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,3))=1,COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,4))=1,COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,5))=1),LARGE(A2:E2,1),IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,1))=1,COUNTIF(A2:E2,LARGE(A2:E2,2))=2),LARGE(A2:E2,2))).

So, here is my concern: How shall I refer in the formula to any match in the range? When I state, IF the 1st Large number has 2 matches AND no other number has more than 2 matches, will I have to enlist all other numbers or somehow can say "highest number of match within the range" in Formula?

Thanks.

Comment: You say that the previous solution worked "for only numerical values". But then you give an example (22, 3, 34, 22, 7) which is precisely that!

Comment: Also, can you give either a link to the previous (array) solution or else just that solution itself? And please let us know over what size ranges that solution "slows down Excel".

Comment: @XORLX You are right, but this is just an example, other examples contain numerical and text values, and sometimes blank cells. The link to the previous question: http://superuser.com/questions/1037491/excel-sort-cells-by-a-number-of-matches/1037516#1037516

Comment: And what should be done with any non-numericals? Can you answer my other query re the size of range which you say causes issues for the array formula, and what precisely the array formula being used is (I assume that the range being referenced is not the same as that within the version in the link you provided)?

Comment: Non-numericals will be sorted as a last priority: 3,2,1,A,B,C,and Blanks as the very last priority. The number of entries got bigger and my worksheets take ages to open, to save and sometimes Excel even refuses to save.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asking to see the actual formula which was responsible for your workbook grinding to a halt. And you say there are no other formulas in the workbook? Also, why are numbers to be sorted in a descending order but alphabetics in an ascending order? Since this is even more complex than the set-up with numerics only, the chance of going from an array set-up to a non-array one is probably almost non-existent. But then, array formulas per se are not a problem; it's the size of the ranges being passed to them which are. Hence why I asked for the specific ranges you are using.

Comment: Ranges are of 5 entries, but there are many ranges per worksheet (up to 27). I used to formula provided by you in the linked question. I can forget non-numerics, but still need blank cells.

Comment: Operating over 135 cells in total, those formulas, as provided, would calculate in a fraction of a second.

Comment: 135 columns and 8,000 rows?

Comment: You said "Ranges are of 5 entries". 5*27=135.

Comment: These are 5 entry-ranges (per formula). These 5 entry ranges are used over and over again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "entry-range". Besides, it's a moot point: in my opinion, in order to deal with non-numeric ordering as well, the formula to solve your current query will, if anything, be far more complex than the previous one. Since the previous version was an array formula, I would imagine it would be virtually impossible to make this newer version non-array.

Comment: Since the goal is " in cells F1 to J1 (No VBA, No Array formulae)".. why not just use some helper column and minimize the formulae for each.. ?(adduce : lower cpu loading per cell formulae)..